# Log configuration changes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to log when configuration is changed.

[I do this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/primitives/change-tokens) in `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`:

```
ChangeToken.OnChange(
  () => configuration.GetReloadToken(),
  state => logger.Information("Configuration reloaded"),
  (object)null
);
```

But I get double change reports, so it needs to be debounced. [The advice is to do this](https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/issues/287):

```
ChangeToken.OnChange(
  () => configuration.GetReloadToken(),
  state => { Thread.Sleep(2000); logger.Information("Configuration reloaded"); },
  (object)null
);
```

I'm using `2000` here as I'm not sure what's a reasonable value.

I've found that sometimes I still get multiple change detections, separated by 2000 milliseconds. So the debounce doesn't work for me, just causes a delay between reported changes. If I set a high value then I only get one report, but that isn't ideal (and conceals the problem).

So I'd like to know:

- **Is this really debouncing, or just queueing reported changes?**
- I've used values from 1000 to 5000 to varying success. What are others using?
- Is the sleep issued to the server's main thread? I hope not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple change detection issue discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2542) (and at least a dozen other issues in multiple repos) is something they refuse to address using a built-in mechanism.

The MS docs use a [file hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-5.0#simple-startup-change-token) approach, but I think that debouncing is better.

My solution uses async (avoids async-in-sync which could blow up something accidentally) and a [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli#ihostedservice-interface) that debounces change detections.

`Debouncer.cs`:

```cs
public sealed class Debouncer : IDisposable {

  public Debouncer(TimeSpan? delay) => _delay = delay ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

  private readonly TimeSpan _delay;
  private CancellationTokenSource? previousCancellationToken = null;

  public async Task Debounce(Action action) {
    _ = action ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    Cancel();
    previousCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try {
      await Task.Delay(_delay, previousCancellationToken.Token);
      await Task.Run(action, previousCancellationToken.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) { }    // can swallow exception as nothing more to do if task cancelled
  }

  public void Cancel() {
    if (previousCancellationToken != null) {
      previousCancellationToken.Cancel();
      previousCancellationToken.Dispose();
    }
  }

  public void Dispose() => Cancel();

}
```

`ConfigWatcher.cs`:

```cs
public sealed class ConfigWatcher : IHostedService, IDisposable {

  public ConfigWatcher(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<ConfigWatcher> logger) {
    _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    _logger = logger;
  }

  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
  private readonly ILogger<ConfigWatcher> _logger;

  private readonly Debouncer _debouncer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

  private void OnConfigurationReloaded() {
    _logger.LogInformation("Configuration reloaded");
    // ... can do more stuff here, e.g. validate config
  }

  public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    ChangeToken.OnChange(
      () => {                                                 // resolve config from scope rather than ctor injection, in case it changes (this hosted service is a singleton)
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var configuration = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        return configuration.GetReloadToken();
      },
      async () => await _debouncer.Debounce(OnConfigurationReloaded)
    );
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;

  public void Dispose() => _debouncer.Dispose();

}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddHostedService<ConfigWatcher>();        // registered as singleton
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, someone else can answer your questions, but I did run into this issue and found this [Gist by cocowalla](https://gist.github.com/cocowalla/5d181b82b9a986c6761585000901d1b8).
The code provided by cocowalla debounces instead of just waiting. It successfully deduplicated the change callback for me.
Cocowalla also includes an extension method so you can simply call `OnChange` on the `IConfiguration`.

Here's a sample:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        configuration.OnChange(() => Console.WriteLine("configuration changed"));

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class Debouncer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly TimeSpan waitTime;
    private int counter;

    public Debouncer(TimeSpan? waitTime = null)
    {
        this.waitTime = waitTime ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    }

    public void Debouce(Action action)
    {
        var current = Interlocked.Increment(ref this.counter);

        Task.Delay(this.waitTime).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
                // Is this the last task that was queued?
                if (current == this.counter && !this.cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                action();

            task.Dispose();
        }, this.cts.Token);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.cts.Cancel();
    }
}

public static class IConfigurationExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform an action when configuration changes. Note this requires config sources to be added with
    /// `reloadOnChange` enabled
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config">Configuration to watch for changes</param>
    /// <param name="action">Action to perform when <paramref name="config"/> is changed</param>
    public static void OnChange(this IConfiguration config, Action action)
    {
        // IConfiguration's change detection is based on FileSystemWatcher, which will fire multiple change
        // events for each change - Microsoft's code is buggy in that it doesn't bother to debounce/dedupe
        // https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2542
        var debouncer = new Debouncer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        ChangeToken.OnChange<object>(config.GetReloadToken, _ => debouncer.Debouce(action), null);
    }
}
```

In the sample, the debounce delay is 3 seconds, for my small json file, the debounce delay stops deduplicating around 230 milliseconds.