# How to keep cancelling the task until a condition is met (TaskCanceledException)

Tags: c#, .net, task, cancellation

I want to call a method after some delay when an event is raised, but any subsequent events should "restart" this delay. Quick example to illustrate, the view should be updated when scrollbar position changes, but only 1 second after the user has finished scrolling.

Now I can see many ways of implementing that, but the most intuitive would be to use `Task.Delay` + `ContinueWith` + cancellation token. However, I am experiencing some issues, more precisely subsequent calls to my function cause the `TaskCanceledException` exception and I started to wonder how I could get rid of that. Here is my code:

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;

private async void Update()
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
    _cts = new();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _cts.Token)
       .ContinueWith(o => Debug.WriteLine("Update now!"), 
       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

I have found a workaround that works pretty nicely, but I would like to make the first idea work.

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;
private CancellationTokenRegistration? _cancellationTokenRegistration;

private void Update()
{
    _cancellationTokenRegistration?.Unregister();
    _cts = new();
    _cancellationTokenRegistration = _cts.Token.Register(() => Debug.WriteLine("Update now!"));
    _cts.CancelAfter(1000);
}
```

Comment: why not something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VJL7KG) `cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` is for cancelling before timeout ... in normal code it may or may not appear (depends if you call `cts?.Cancel();`

Comment: @Selvin in this case the update function would never be called, because the task would always be cancelled. I could just wrap my code with `try/catch`  and that would work, I was just trying to get rid of this exception in the first place

Comment: *in this case the update function would never be called* no kidding? that was just an example to show that you may use `try/catch` ... and `TaskCanceledException` will be called as long as somewhere internally calls `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on given token which you cannot avoid

Comment: @Selvin Well, then you could just say "why not use try catch"

Comment: because I wana show working code example on dotnetfiddle ... To avoid another question like "how"

Comment: You may want to look into using `System.Reactive`: if you feed your event into an Observable, then you can `Throttle` it to 1 second to get the "debounce" behavior you're looking for. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28472505/120955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

You didn't say hat UI you're using, so for Windows Forms also add `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and for WPF `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading`.

Then you can do this:

```
Panel panel = new Panel(); // assuming this is a scrollable control

IObservable<EventPattern<ScrollEventArgs>> query =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<ScrollEventHandler, ScrollEventArgs>(
            h => panel.Scroll += h,
            h => panel.Scroll -= h)
        .Select(sea => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(_ => sea))
        .Switch();
    
IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(sea => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
```

The `query` is firing for every `Scroll` event and starts a one second timer. The `Switch` operator watches for every `Timer` produces and only connects to the latest one produced, thus ignoring the previous `Scroll` events.

And that's it.

After scrolling has a 1 second pause the word "Hello" is written to the console. If you begin scrolling again then after every further 1 second pause it fires again.

Comment: I use Avalonia framework, so I had to adjust the code a little bit (remove `ScrollEventHandler` and change `ScrollEventArgs` to `ScrollChangedEventArgs`). Nevertheless, the code looks neat and it is a good alternative to the workaround I described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In my own experience I've dealt with lots of scenarios just like the one you describe, e.g. *update something one second after the mouse stops moving* etc.

For a long time I would do timer restarts just the way you describe, by cancelling an old task and starting a new one. But I never really liked how messy that was, so I came up with an alternative that I use in production code. Long-term it has proven quite reliable. It takes advantage of the captured context associated with a task. Multiple instances of `TaskCanceledException` no longer occur.

```
class WatchDogTimer
{
    int _wdtCount = 0;
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    public void Restart(Action onRanToCompletion)
    {
        _wdtCount++;
        var capturedCount = _wdtCount;
        Task
            .Delay(Interval)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                // If the 'captured' localCount has not changed after awaiting the Interval, 
                // it indicates that no new 'bones' have been thrown during that interval.        
                if (capturedCount.Equals(_wdtCount))
                {
                    onRanToCompletion();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Another nice perk is that it doesn't rely on platform timers and works just as well in iOS/Android as it does in WinForms/WPF.

---

For purposes of demonstration, this can be exercised in a quick console demo where the `MockUpdateView()` action is sent to the WDT 10 times at 500 ms intervals. It will only execute one time, 500 ms after the last restart is received.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Test WDT";
        var wdt = new WatchDogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500) };

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        // "Update view 500 ms after the last restart."
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            wdt.Restart(onRanToCompletion: ()=>MockUpdateView());
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void MockUpdateView()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Update now! WDT expired {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }
}
```

---

So, with 500 ms times 10 restarts this verifies one event at 5 seconds from the start.

[image: console output]

Comment: There's also a dumb WinForms demo game that got named [KikTheDog](https://github.com/IVSoftware/watch-dog-timer-game.git) after someone on this very site described restarting a watchdog timer as "giving it a kick" though my dog and I prefer to think of it as "throwing it a bone".

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a state variable and a delay to avoid messing with  timers or task cancelation. This is far simpler IMO.

Add this state variable to your class/form:

```
private DateTime _nextRefresh = DateTime.MaxValue;
```

And here's how you refresh:

```
private async void Update() 
{
    await RefreshInOneSecond();
}

private async Task RefreshInOneSecond()
{
    _nextRefresh = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    if (_nextRefresh <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        _nextRefresh = DateTime.MaxValue;
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

If you call `RefreshInOneSecond` repeatedly, it pushes out the `_nextRefresh` timestamp until later, so any refreshes already in flight will do nothing.

[Demo on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JTnmuM)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a timer and reset this whenever the user does something. For example using `System.Timers.Timer`

```
timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.SynchronizingObject = myControl; // Needs a winforms object for synchronization
timer.Elapsed += OnElapsed; 
timer.Start(); // Don't forget to stop the timer whenever you are done

...
private void OnUserUpdate(){
    timer.Interval = 1000; // Setting the interval will reset the timer
}
```

There are multiple timers to chose from, I believe the same pattern is possible with the other timers. [DispatchTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) might be most suitable if you use WPF.

Note that both `System.Timers.Timer` and `Task.Delay` uses `System.Threading.Timer` in the background. It is possible to use this directly, just call the [.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.change?view=net-7.0) method to reset it. But be aware that this raises the event on a taskpool thread, so you need to provide your own synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the same scenario in a JavaScript application using Timer. I believe it's the same in the .NET world. Anyway handling this use-case when the user calls a method repeatedly with `Task.Delay()` will put more pressure on GC & thread pool

```
var timer = new Timer()
{
    Enabled = true,
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds,
};

timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    timer.Stop();
    // do stuff
}
    
void OnKeyUp()
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Start();
}
```